# Couldn't locate an element by these strategies: By.id; OpenQA.Selenium.WebdriverTimeoutExceltpion: Timed out after 1 seconds

Tags: c#, macos, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-mac, safaridriver

I have written an automation framework in VS2017 using Selenium Webdriver in C# and PageObjects. That is working absolutely fine in windows. Same PageObjects code is used in VS2017 for MAC OS and it is not working there giving

OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Couldn't locate an element by these strategies: By.Id: userNameInput;

----> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 1 seconds

I have moved my code from VS2017 For Windows to VS2017 for Mac. That is successfully converted and compiled. There were problems however i have resolved the webdriver related issues and now code is working perfectly to Launch Chrome & Safari. But whenever i try to find elements, the exception occurs. I have implemented Explicitwaits and other parameters but both Safari and Chrome are giving me errors at some stage in finding the elements. I have also tried finding the elements without POM but that doesn't work too.

Considering the following function i have written to Signout user from Dynamics CRM

```
    public void UserSignOut(ref ExtentTest test)
    {
        WDEx.SwitchWindows(0);
        Browser.Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
        UserIcon.Click();
        SignOut.Click();
    }
```

where 
UserIcon is

```
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = @"navTabButtonChangeProfileImageLink")]
    public IWebElement UserIcon { get; set; }
```

and SignOut is

```
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "navTabButtonUserInfoSignOutId")]
    private IWebElement SignOut { get; set; }
```

It should work exactly the way as it is working on Windows Chromedriver with VS2017. If anybody could provide a solution then that could be very time saving for me. Thankful in Advance. Cheers!

Comment: Have you checked that the markup displayed in Safari on MacOS is the same as the markup displayed in Safari on Windows?  Safari on Windows is deprecated and very old

Comment: Hi. Thanks for prompt response. I have edited the explanation with Chrome driver on windows VS2017. Can you please share your experience on Mac safari driver with VS2017 for mac having dot net core 2.1?

Comment: @Ardesco and yes. Markup is same. Elements are having same ids which are there on windows. Except those are not identified in mac safari and execution is lot slower

Comment: I’d be curious what the `SwitchWindows` method is doing. If it’s blindly switching to a window and expecting index 0 to be the first window opened during the session, that’s a time bomb just waiting to go off.

Comment: @JimEvans that has nothing to do with the problem. Actually when signing out the app it makes sure that windows is the base one and not the multiple opened.

Comment: @JimEvans original problem is related to identifying the elements on which exception occurs. I tried using the same by removing the switchwindows function and still same error persists

Comment: @Faran, it sounds like a classic wait problem, have you tried using an Explicit wait to check for the existence of the element before you attempt to interact with it?

Comment: @Ardesco Yes, you are correct. i have tried identifying the element through explicit wait. Sometimes it gets known and sometimes timeout occurs. but the problem is here that in my following function i Click on the element through explicit wait identification and when i want to pass value through sendkeys to that particular element it doesn't work. see the sample Code below
`WDEx.JSExeClick(WDEx.FindElement(By.id("crmGrid_findCriteria"), WDEx.delayAvg));`
while `WDEx` is a static class contains helping methods, and `JSExeClick`is a function to click on element through `IJavaScriptExecutor`.

Comment: @Ardesco immediately i click on that element, i try to pass value through
`Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.id("crmGrid_findCriteria")).sendkeys("Example Text");`
it never identifies that element again, despite the cursor being on that same element.